# How to get all png from a specific folder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, directory

I would like to get all png in a specific folder in Xcode. I am currently using this code right now to get PNG file.

```
(Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "png", inDirectory: nil) as NSArray).enumerateObjects({ obj, idx, stop in
        var path = (obj as! NSString).lastPathComponent
        print("Path - ",path)
})
```

but this get all PNG from all folder for example - [Example-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQvrr.png)

I would like to get images only inside the Fonts folder. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I look at your code, I assume you want to get all image paths from Fonts folder from Bundle App Folder. In this case, you must make your Fonts folder to be Reference Folder (blue icon), not Group folder (yellow icon), like this:
[image]

You can drag your folder in your Project Navigator, it will display this box:
[image]

Be sure to choose Create Folder References and choose your project target.

The reason is Reference folder is a real folder in your Bundle. All files in Group Folder will be flatted, which mean they are all in the root directory of your Bundle, then you won't know the parent folder of these files.

Then you can use your code to retrieve the png (+ you should specify "Fonts" for inDirectory parameter):

```
(Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "png", inDirectory: "Fonts") as NSArray).enumerateObjects({ obj, idx, stop in
    var path = (obj as! NSString).lastPathComponent
    print("Path - ",path)
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform these two steps to achieve your goal.

1. Pass the folder name in `inDirectory` argument.
   Something like this:
   `let pngs = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "png", inDirectory: "Fonts")`
2. Make sure that the `Fonts` directory is added into project as `Folder Reference` instead of a `Group`.
   [image: Selecting Folder References instead of Groups]

Hope this helps